# Swagger codegen typescript: model name matches existing language type

Tags: java, typescript, swagger-codegen

I've coded this documentation annotations:

```
@ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(code=HttpStatus.SC_CONFLICT, response = ResponseError.class),
    @ApiResponse(code=HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, response = ResponseError.class),
    @ApiResponse(code=HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST, response = ResponseError.class),
    @ApiResponse(code=HttpStatus.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, response = ResponseError.class)
})
public ResponseEntity<User> addUser(
```

As you can see it's returning an `ResponseError` class. `ResponseError` is third-party class I'm not able to change and it looks like:

```
package cat.gencat.ctti.canigo.arch.web.rs.response;
public class ResponseError {
    private java.util.List<cat.gencat.ctti.canigo.arch.web.rs.model.Error> errors;
```

I'm using maven `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` plugin in order to generate my TypeScript model classes.

Currently, I'm getting this warning message:

> Error (model name matches existing language type) cannot be used as a model name. Renamed to ModelError

As far I've been able to figure out, it's renaming `cat.gencat.ctti.canigo.arch.web.rs.model.Error` class to `ModelError`.

So, an `modelError.ts` class code is generated:

```
export interface ModelError {
    code?: number;
    message?: string;
}
```

However, if I take a look on generated `responseError.ts` class, it's using an `Error` class yet.

```
export interface ResponseError {
    errors?: Array<Error>;
}
```

Any ideas?